# Badness underful box and weird output near equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, align

```
\begin{align}
 &{V_L}^{det}=-I_2+\frac{(1+c_1-2c_2/I2)^2X)}{9(r-\alpha)}\\
 &+(4^{\beta_1-1}9^{2-\beta_1}(-2c_1I_2+(c_2+I_2){{I_F}^*}^2)(\alpha-r)X 
 \\
 &\left(\frac{(-1+b)c_1(-1+{I_F}^*)[(-c_2 - I_2) {I_F}^* + c_1I_2(1 +{I_F}^*)]X}{b_1 I_2 {{I_F}^*}^3 (\alpha - r)\right)}^{\beta_1-1}\cdot
 \\&{{I_F}^*}^2
 (4 c_2^2 - 4 (1 + c_1) c_2 I_2 + I_2^2 (1 - 81 a^2 + 2 c_1 + c_1^2 - 9 a (I_2 - 18 r) + 9 I_2 r - 81 r^2))))
 \label{eq: leaderA}
 \end{align}
```

I have this code and once I run it it shows first of all underfull box warning. If for the last line I just add something simple (e.g. replace the last line with the number 2) it will show somehow the equation but also near the numbering we see a text "subsection" which I find really weird. The code works only if I remove the last alignment tab which I also find weird. What should I do?

Comment: The code doesn't compile; perhaps the `}` brace after `\right)` should go before it.

Comment: ok apparently that was the problem :P.Thanks so much, sometimes its good to have a set of other eyes look at it :D

Comment: simple typo, fixed by egreg's comment